# \[DifferentialD] not displayed correctly in Mathematica StackExchange

Tags: discussion, feature-request, code-formatting

`\[DifferentialD]` apparently does not have a Unicode representation, so I had to enter it directly in a reformatting of question [83672](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83675/adding-noise-to-nonlinear-ode-system).  However, I noticed that it is displayed in blue, as if it were an unknown variable.  A minor issue, perhaps, but I think this should be fixed.

**Addendum**

In light of the comment by Histograms, I suggest that it would be better yet for Mathematica StackExchange to interpret and display this character rather than just inserting a blank (probably non-printing) character.  The same is true of `\[Distributed]` and, perhaps, other Mathematica characters.

Comment: `\[DifferentialD]` has unicode U+F74C but I think it's in the private use area so there's no guarantee it will render properly without the right font.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/DifferentialD.html

Comment: @Histograms. That code will only represent `\[DifferentialD]` in _Mathematica_. It will **not** show the _Mathematica_ glyph in a browser.

Comment: @m_goldberg yeah I know, as I understand, bbgodfrey's issue was more about colouring. It would be great if somehow we could use Mathematica's fonts as web fonts as I think it's in a TrueType font called Mathematica7_regular but that sounds like a recipe for confusion

Comment: @Histograms  TrueType font Mathematica7 does have this character, and Mathematica recognizes it, but it displays as `d` here.

Comment: Wait... Is there a way to get Mathematica special characters to auto format here? I always manually change them using a unicode table form wiki...

Comment: @ChipHurst See Meta [1463](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/installing-halirutans-script-in-internet-explorer-11) and references therein for Halirutan's excellent approach.  However, I use Silvia's approach in [1137](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/how-to-copy-as-unicode-from-a-notebook). because I use Windows and do not like third party add-ons of uncertain provenance.  I installed it as a palette and would be happy to share it with you.

Comment: @ChipHurst And another alternative is http://steampiano.net/msc/